# Combine two files

Tags: php, file

I have two files I want to combine two files by name in an other file.

My first file (3 columns ID;Name;Comment):

```
2538;API plazza - NOV-16;acceuil chef de projet... Nicolas pour    briefing.
2538;API plazza - NOV-16;exposer les produits de Jive software
2538;API plazza - NOV-16;objectifs de securité.... OPE = secirité ? 
2538;API plazza - NOV-16;MoA HR pas simple... 
2538;API plazza - NOV-16;grosse pression pour livrer vite et en charge MoE OBS + consultant OBS pour deploiement Jive...
```

My second file (2 columns ID2;Name):

```
TK-135;API plazza - NOV-16
```

I want to have in my third file (4 columns ID2;ID;Name;Comment).

My code:

```
    $tab1 = file('fichier1');
    $tab2 = file('fichier2');


    $taille = count($tab2);
    for($i=0;$i<$taille;$i++){

            $vars = explode(';',$tab2[$i]);

            $taille2 = count($tab1);
            //echo $vars[1];

            for($j=0;$j<$taille2;$j++){
                    $vars2=explode(';',$tab1[$j]);
                     //echo $vars2[1];


                    if(isset($vars[1])){
                            if($vars2[1]==$vars[1]){
                                   file_put_contents('f.txt',$vars2[0].';'.$tab2[$j],FILE_APPEND);
                            }
                    }

            }
    }
```

But I don't know why the condition if($vars2[1]==$vars[1]) is false...

Thank you.

Comment: Can you please tell column length of "fichier1" and "fichier2"?

Comment: How can I tell column length??

Comment: Can you share sample of both files?

Comment: I've already shared in the post

Comment: I just tested you script as is with sample data provided in your post and it worked fine.

Comment: I test it also now but it's only a portion of my files. With all of the two files the  condition doesn't work and I don't know why.